# Why is this set not recursively enumerable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I need to show why this set is not recursively enumerable:
$\{i \mid W_i=\emptyset\}$.

Here $W_i$ is the set of things that can be accepted by the Turing machine $M_i$.

I know that for a set to recursively enumerable, it must be accepted by a Turing machine so that the Turing machine can enumerate over all the elements in that set. Here, I do not understand why a Turing machine wouldn't be able to enumerate over the elements of this set.

Can someone provide an explanation of why this set is not recursively enumerable or hint at a method that can be used to show this?

Comment: If a Turing machine hasn't halted and hasn't accepted something, how do you know it won't accept something in the future?  You should look for a way to formalize the statement that if you could solve this you can solve the halting problem.

Comment: On those same lines, do you have any thoughts on how $\{i \mid W_i= \mathbb{Z}\}$ can be shown to not be recursively enumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to show some language is not in $RE$ (recursively enumerable) is to show a reduction from a known language which is not in $RE$ such as $\overline{HP}$.

the reduction may be as follows:
$$f(\left < M \right >, x) = i_{M_x} $$

where  $i_{M_x}$ is the index of the machine $M_x$ described bellow:

$M_x$ on input $w$:

1. run M on x
2. accept

I'll leave the correctness proof to you.